# Function "rep" inside an "ifelse" does not return any repetition

Tags: r

If I type

`ifelse(TRUE, rep(1,10), 0)`

I get `1` instead of `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`.

Why? Is this a bug? How can I get the vector of ones?

Comment: Another funny and for some scenarios a handy solution: `x <- T; rep(+x, 9*x+1)` where you either `rep(1, 10)` on `T` or `rep(0, 1)` on `F`

Answer (score 2):

Because `ifelse` is vectorized, it:

> returns a value with the same shape as test

Since your test is just a single element vector, your return is just the first element of `rep(1, 10)`.

What you want is `if`, which expects a single boolean, and then runs the following code, whatever it might be. If you want to return your `else` statement, then we explicitly include `else` as below.

```r
if (TRUE) rep(1,10) else 0
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `ifelse` is vectorized. That means, your output dimensions aligns with the condition. In your code, since condition `TRUE` is a single value, your output should also be a single value. That's why you get `1` instead of `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`.

---

You can try

```
> ifelse(rep(TRUE,10), 1, 0)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

or

```
> unlist(ifelse(TRUE, list(rep(1, 10)), 0))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: But this is not the same functionality. I need a vector from comparing a single value.

Comment: This is not answering the question. OP asks for the "why" of this behavior.

Comment: @Jaap yes, you are right, I added some comments.

Comment: @quesadagranja See my update